# How to make a .cshtml pop window in ASP .NET Core MVC web application

Tags: razor, popup, popupwindow

I am a newbie to programming & I am trying to make a ASP .NET Core MVC web application. There I have to upload a user profile image. To do this I should make a pop up window like in Facebook. (As an example, when user clicked on camera icon instead of going to another page, a pop window to upload image has to be appeared.)

Following is the line in the `Profile.cshtml` page that redirects to the `UploadUserImage.cshtml` page that should appear as a popup window. (that file is very large that is why I thought to publish only this line)

```
 <a asp-action="UploadUserImage" asp-controller="UserImages"><i class="fas fa-camera camera-icon-profile"></i></a>
```

And following is the .cshtml file that has to be appear as popup upon clicking the above link.

***UploadUserImage.cshtml***

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.User>

@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Profile.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Upload your photo";
}
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadProfilePicture", "UserImageUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Upload your picture</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <input type="file" name="file" />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Save Photo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          }
       </div>
     }
   </div>
</div>
```

I got to know that by a front end jQuery can be used to make the popup window appear. but I do not know how to apply it. Can please somebody let me know how to do it?

Thank you very much for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. - Create a PartialView to your UploadPage
2. - Search and install [Magnific-Popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) packages
3. - Create a Function to call the Popup Window in the Html

```js
    <script>
        
          function ShowPopup(idUserProfile) {
                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
            
                            url: "@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")",
            
                            data: { idUserProfile },
            
                            success: function (response) {
            
            
                                $.magnificPopup.open({
            
                                    items: {
            
                                        src: response
            
                                    },
            
                                    type: 'inline',
            
                                    modal: true,
            
                                    closeOnBgClick: false,
            
                                    focus: '#btnDismiss'
            
                                });
                            },
            
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            
                            }
            
                    });
                }
                </script>
```

maybe you don´t use the `idUserProfile`

4. - In the Controller class call the partial View

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    return PartialView("_UploadPage");
}
```

5. - In Html to call the Function

     ```
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowPopup()">Show Upload</button>
     ```

Comment: You mean, I should install NuGet package called Magnific.Popup?

Comment: Yup, or download the packages on the Magnificpopup site and import to your application in the scripts folder

Comment: I am sorry your answer is not working. I followed the steps, but it seems nothing is happening. In the console it gives the errors: I have attached the errors image to the question. Can you please help me to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: try to import the Ajax unobtrusive library and make sure you imported the libraries in your HTML

Comment: Yes, Felipe I did it as in the documentation. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`  `<script src="/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>` & `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/magnific-popup.css">` (the .js and .css files are in wroot folder at particular locations). Can't understand what went wrong.

Comment: put break-point in the controller partial view and see what happen

Comment: Yes, I will check and let you know.

Comment: I checked it as you said. Although the button is clicked, it does not even call the function `ShowPopup`. Which means the function is not called by clicking the button. So, here what can I do, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232661/discussion-between-felipe-cruz-and-abimani).